# Mixed Content warning over http

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, mixed-content

I've deployed my django rest framework project, it works fine and running on docker, the site is loading over https but images, videos are being loaded over http, and getting Mixed content warning, and browser also showing insecure even if actual site has ssl certifate. I searched for related questions but didn't solve my problem.
**mysite.conf**

```
server {
    server_name cp.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3180; # docker container listens here
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cp.mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cp.mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = cp.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name cp.mysite.com www.cp.mysite.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**docker nginx.conf**

```
upstream django {
    server django:5000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/media/;
    }
}
```

**settings.py**

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT", default=True)
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 518400
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = env.bool(
    "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS", default=True
)
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD", default=True)

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = env.bool(
    "DJANGO_SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF", default=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you might need to follow:

- Double check the videos and images urls, ensure that is has a leading https protocol
- Update the static urls to use https protocol
- Check your Docker configurations for the https port